# Cut data when values transition from low to high or high to low using python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I was wondering if there was a way (possibly using Pandas) to cut a dataset (table below) into groups when the value of B transitions either above or below a set value:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 15 |
| 3 | 12 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 7 | 4 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 9 | 14 |
| 10 | 11 |

For instance if the transition value was 6 then they would be grouped like:

| A | B | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | A |
| 2 | 15 | A |
| 3 | 12 | A |
| 4 | 2 | B |
| 5 | 5 | B |
| 6 | 3 | B |
| 7 | 4 | B |
| 8 | 2 | B |
| 9 | 14 | C |
| 10 | 11 | C |

It's important that there are distinct groups and not just everything above/below 6 being in one group

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
df['Group'] = df['A'].ge(df['B']).ne(df['A'].ge(df['B']).shift()).cumsum()
```

```
>>> df
    A   B  Group
0   1  10      1
1   2  15      1
2   3  12      1
3   4   2      2
4   5   5      2
5   6   3      2
6   7   4      2
7   8   2      2
8   9  14      3
9  10  11      3
```

If you want letter: `df['Group'].add(64).apply(chr)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion. Not the shortest, but it works:

```
import itertools  

l=[(i>6)*1 for i in df.B.to_list()]

m = [(i, list(k)) for i, k in itertools.groupby(l))]

vals = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']

res= []

for i in range(len(m)):
    res.extend([vals[i]]*len(m[i][1]))

df['Group'] = res

>>>print(df)

    A   B Group
0   1  10     A
1   2  15     A
2   3  12     A
3   4   2     B
4   5   5     B
5   6   3     B
6   7   4     B
7   8   2     B
8   9  14     C
9  10  11     C
```